# Netbeans and refactoring code inside edited-protected block written by Matisse gui

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring, matisse

I wrote a swing lib and i used it into my project with matisse.

Now i want do some name-packaging-change, a very simple operation but the problem is refactoring can't touch the code written by matisse (locked for editing).

So the question is:
There is a smart way to refactor all without opening my java classes in external file-editor and hand-replace what i have to replace?

Thank all.

PS. Why a great and powerful IDE like Netbeans fall in this kind of troubles?

Comment: I can refactor anything _outside_ the fold in the usual way; I can change the properties of things inside the fold by right-clicking on the item in the inspector window. Perhaps you could elaborate on what's not working.

Comment: @trashgod: I want refractor the code INSIDE locked folds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code *inside* the fold is generated based on properties specified in the GUI designer. Fields can be renamed and the code customized as desired by right-clicking on the inspector window. The `Code Customizer` dialog, new to version 6.1.9, is particularly convenient for this.